# Automapper re-map only a child object to existing flattened VM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, viewmodel, automapper-6

I have a parent and child domain object being mapped to a single ViewModel object. E.G.

```
class Parent
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Child Child {get;set;}
}

class Child
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

class ParentChildVM
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int ChildID {get;set;}
    public string ChildName {get; set;}
}
```

The types are mapped in static configuration file and it just uses the built in naming conventions to map the properties and achieve the flattening.

I'm using this `ParentChildVM` with an ASP.NET MVC view that puts `ID` and `Name` in form inputs, but only *displays* `ChildID` and `ChildName`. Since the `Child`'s properties are not in form fields, they are not posted back to the server upon saving and are empty in the `ParentChildVM` that is reconstructed from the posted values.

So I want to remap the `Child` domain object to my `ParentChildVM` to fill in the missing properties. But I don't want to map the `Parent` again because it would overwrite the edited values. Is there any way to map a given `Child` instance into my existing `ParentChildVM` with AutoMapper (v6.1.1.0)?

EDIT:

I guess I know I could add a mapping from `Child` -> `ParentChildVM` and then use `.ForMember` to tell it how to map `ChildID` and `ChildName`, but in reality there are a lot more properties so what I'm asking is: is there a way to do it and still take advantage of the naming-convention-based mapping? I.E. keep using the "Auto" part of AutoMapper.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html